# Add Custom Post Type to Algolia index

Tags: wordpress, algolia

the WordPress Theme I am using has some custom post types that come as part of an aditional plugin. Those post types are not available for indexing with Algolia. Can I add them for indexing to the searchable_posts index somehow?

I guess this is the relevant code in the plugin:

```
private function init() {

        $this->setup_constants();

        // Actions
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'load_languages' ), 11 );
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'init_settings' ), 99 );
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_post_type' ), 100 );
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_taxonomies' ), 101 );
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_boxes_function' ) );
        add_action( 'pre_post_update', array( $this, 'pre_post_update_function' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_meta_box_data' ) );
        add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', array( $this, 'add_meta_box_after_title' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'change_destination_menu' ) );
        add_action( 'edit_form_top', array( $this, 'edit_form_top_func' ) );         // need to tabs output
        add_action( 'pre_get_posts', array( $this, 'sort_destinations_by_meta_value' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_footer', array( $this, 'language_switcher_fix' ) );

        // Filters
        add_filter( 'template_include', array( $this, 'para_destination_templates') );
        add_filter( 'request', array( $this, 'alter_the_query' ) );
        add_filter( 'wp_title', array( $this, 'page_name_wp_title' ), 10, 2 );
        add_filter( 'wp_link_query', array($this, 'wp_link_query_destination' ), 10, 2 );

        add_filter( 'oembed_discovery_links', array($this, 'oembed_discovery_links_rf' ), 10, 2 );
        add_filter( 'previous_post_rel_link', array( $this, 'previous_post_rel_link_rf' ) );
        add_filter( 'next_post_rel_link', array( $this, 'next_post_rel_link_rf' ) );

        add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', array($this, 'fix_menu_url_info_pages'), 10, 3 );
        add_filter( 'preview_post_link', array($this, 'fix_preview_link' ) );
        // WP Init
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'load_scripts' ) );

        // Settings
        $this->settings = get_destination_settings();

        // Create objects
        $this->master = new Travel_Master_Pages_CPT( $this->settings );
        $this->list = new Travel_Directory_CPT( $this->settings );
        $this->map = new Destination_Maps( $this->settings, false );

        // Compatibility
        $this->backward();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the searchable posts index will contain all post types that are not flagged as excluded from search.

Here is the exact code line we use to fetch those:

```php
$searchable_post_types = get_post_types( array( 'exclude_from_search' => false ), 'names' );
```

The only way to index post types that are excluded from search is to make sure that the post type isn't excluded from search anymore:

```php
<?php

// functions.php

add_action( 'init', 'update_my_custom_type', 99 );

function update_my_custom_type() {
    global $wp_post_types;

    if ( post_type_exists( 'my-custom-type' ) ) {

        // exclude from search results
        $wp_post_types['my-custom-type']->exclude_from_search = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Those post types are not flagged or excluded from search. When I deactivate the Algolia Plugin they do appear in the search results. The code for the functions.php does not help.

Comment: Do you mind sharing how does post types are registered? I think that the problem is that the theme probably only registers the post types with some hooks that might not be triggered during indexing.

Comment: Hi rayrutjes, I added to the original post, what I think might be the relevant code.